# Facebook integration in android?

Tags: android, facebook, integration

Hi Am trying to Integrate Facebook in my application so for that i was guided from [Integration guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)

But i got error in step 3,When am importing,console showing some errors like

```
[2013-03-08 10:16:07 - MessagesTask] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 10:17:00 - MessagesTask] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:57:54 - ProfilePictureSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:57:54 - BooleanOGSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:57:54 - Hackbook] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:57:55 - GraphApiSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:57:55 - Scrumptious] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:57:55 - PlacePickerSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:57:55 - SessionLoginSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:57:55 - FriendPickerSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:57:55 - HelloFacebookSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:57:55 - FacebookSDK] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:57:56 - SwitchUserSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:58:05 - ProfilePictureSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\gtm\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\samples\ProfilePictureSample\bin\jarlist.cache
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - FacebookSDK] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - ProfilePictureSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - BooleanOGSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - Hackbook] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - GraphApiSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - Scrumptious] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - PlacePickerSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - SessionLoginSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - FriendPickerSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - HelloFacebookSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - SwitchUserSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - FacebookSDK] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\gtm\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\facebook\bin\jarlist.cache
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - ProfilePictureSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\gtm\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\samples\ProfilePictureSample\bin\jarlist.cache
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - BooleanOGSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\gtm\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\samples\BooleanOGSample\bin\jarlist.cache
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - Hackbook] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\gtm\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\samples\Hackbook\bin\jarlist.cache
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - GraphApiSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\gtm\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\samples\GraphApiSample\bin\jarlist.cache
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - Scrumptious] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\gtm\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\samples\Scrumptious\bin\jarlist.cache
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - PlacePickerSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\gtm\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\samples\PlacePickerSample\bin\jarlist.cache
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - SessionLoginSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\gtm\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\samples\SessionLoginSample\bin\jarlist.cache
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - FriendPickerSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\gtm\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\samples\FriendPickerSample\bin\jarlist.cache
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - HelloFacebookSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\gtm\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\samples\HelloFacebookSample\bin\jarlist.cache
[2013-03-08 15:58:07 - SwitchUserSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\gtm\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\samples\SwitchUserSample\bin\jarlist.cache
```

So Could you please help me out from this problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

that's because you don't have API level 8 in your SDK. Right click on the project then go to Properties > Android & select another available API

Comment: What if I have it installed and set and build target? I have added and removed the sdk many times, tried different versions, new workspaces, different computer... See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698925/unable-to-add-facebook-sdk-to-project

Answer (score 3):

Open **Android SDK Manager** and install **Android 2.2 (API 8)**

Answer (score 2):

If API level 8 not installed, then install it using the Android SDK.

If already installed, right click on the project.. Properties>Android. Select the build path as Android 2.2 (API Level 8)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to Install API 8.

Hope its helps !

Comment: Could you post your manifest xml ? Have you tried to  Install Android 2.2 API 8  through Android SDK Manager ? If yu imported an another project using android 2.2  API 8, Check the manisfest of that project !

Comment: No issues Now .. I Just Restarted Eclipse then i fixed up project properties its working ..Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

just add this in manifest

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" android:maxSdkVersion="17"/>
```

Comment: Please don't set maxSDKVersion unless it's absolutely necessary (why would you do this?)