# Unable to add facebook sdk to project

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I imported the Facebook SDK as library project into eclipse. I did it by checking Copy projects into Workspace and by leaving it unchecked as well (for some reason the [description](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) says that I must uncheck it).

I tried importing **Existing Projects into Workspace** and **Existing Android Code Into Workspace** as well.

The library checkbox is checked in the properties.
A Facebook sdk has never been imported into this workspace yet.

I created a new project that runs smoothly without Facebook. In the properties, Android tab, I added the library project. It showed a green tick, but when I open that tab again, it shows a red x.
The target of the project is API level 19, the target of the facebook library is API level 8. I also tried it with API level 10
I am using Java compiler 1.6 in both the project and the library.

What I don't understand is that the sample projects that came with the SDK seem to have successfully imported the SDK (green tick), however they all point to the same problem "The import android.support cannot be resolved" on **import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity**; I had to hover over the line and click Fix Project setup to make them work. Then I went to  **Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export -> clicked v4 support library checkbox**. So at least they work. Why do they successfully load the Facebook SDK and why is my app unable to do it?

The Facebook SDK has no libs folder so I guess an interference between different v4 support libraries is out of the question.

I have tried this on two different computers as well.

[image]

[image]

I decided to install Android from step to step instead of the ADT Bundle. I downloaded Eclipse Juno for Java Developers, installed the newest Java version (1.8) and installed the Android packages. Created a new project and imported the facebook sdk 3.5 (tried 3.0.2 and 3.8 as well). I still get the red X.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: But have you copy that project while importing facebook SDK project in your workspace??

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue half a year later and my earlier answer was of no help. The trick is that you need to have the library on the same drive as your project, which is usually the C: drive. That's all. Thank you Facebook for not notifying us about this..

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Here is what I did to solve this strange error.

1. Copy the contents of project.properties file.
2. Delete project.properties file.
3. Create a new file and name it project.properties
4. Paste the contents of the previous file into this new file.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but your answer doesn't solve it for me

Comment: Neither one solves it. The issue is weird, I seem to have done everything correctly, but the project shows Xed as mentioned by OP.